# Javascript fn that can accept single url or multiple URLS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am slightly new to javascript so require the help of you guys

I want to implement  a Javascript function that can take a Array of URl's as  parameter.
and stores them in a array which is a member of the class.
The problem how to know if the array has single URl or multiple url's
Since the url's itself is a string. I dont want to store duplicate URL's

```
function storeUrl(urlArray) {
    var i = 0;
    var url;
    this.myArray = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++) {
        // check whether the URL already exists
        if (this.myArray.indexOf(urlArray[i] == -1) {
            this.myArray.push(urlArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an error from copying, or actually something wrong with your code?  `this.myArray.indexOf(urlArray[i]` (missing the end `)`)

Comment: [typeof()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Ups, your right. A mistake on my part but I'm no longer allowed to change it...

Comment: @Andreas: don't worry, it's not that important.

Comment: sorry missed the ) at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to deal with this without duplicating code, is to turn urlArray to an array with a single element if it isn't one already.

```
function storeUrl(urlArray) {
    urlArray = (urlArray instanceof Array) ? urlArray : [urlArray]; // <- magic
    // urlArray is an Array at this point
    var i = 0;
    var url;
    this.myArray = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++) {
        // check whether the URL already exists
        if (this.myArray.indexOf(urlArray[i] == -1) {
            this.myArray.push(urlArray[i]);
        }
    }
}

// Usage:
storeUrl('myurl');
storeUrl(['url1', 'url2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Working example**](http://jsbin.com/EhuPEbI/3/edit)

You can use the fact the an object  have  unique entries (properties) names :

```
var g = {};
function storeUrl(urlArray)
  {
      if (!Array.isArray(urlArray)) urlArray=[urlArray]; //now you can pass single url also

      for (var i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++)
      {
          if (!g.hasOwnProperty(urlArray[i]))

              {
                  g[urlArray[i]] = urlArray[i];
              }

          //... do whatever with g..
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you to use arguments object which is available inside a javascript function.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

so instead of passing an [] of strings just pass strings
and do something like this

```
function(){
 var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
 for(i=0;i<args.length;i++)
 {
   //access args
 }
}
```

then you can just call the method wherever you want passing any number of arguments. which can be done in javascript using `.apply()`